# I have a background image that is loading only partially

Tags: image, loading

I have a background image that loads mostly, but half of the time there is a pice missing from the image and you have to refresh the page to get the entire image to show. Could the image I'm using be corrupt or broken? Or could the problem be somewhere else. I am using a mac and google chrome.

here is the link: http://wlsnook.staging.wpengine.com/

Comment: I'm not too sure what's wrong with it. The background image looks fine for me. Could you add a link or upload a picture of what the background image is supposed to look like? that could help

Comment: 2000×2238 is kinda big for a background image and I can see some part of the chain from server to screen getting a bit overwhelmed trying to render that. It's also a design that probably looks great on your 100cm display but looks pretty lousy on my 5cm phone.